# How to format Rebol errors as strings?

Tags: string, exception, error-handling, rebol, rebol3

Rebol's error! type comes back as an object you can inspect and extract properties out of.

```
>> result: try [1 / 0]
** Math error: attempt to divide by zero
** Where: / try
** Near: / 0

>> probe result
make error! [
    code: 400
    type: 'Math
    id: 'zero-divide
    arg1: none
    arg2: none
    arg3: none
    near: [/ 0]
    where: [/ try]
]
...
```

Note that when that error bubbles up to the console and is the last value of the chain of the evaluation, it turns it into a string and presents it to the user.  e.g. *"Math error: attempt to divide by zero"*.

How do I generate this string in my own code?  I know I can dig into the `system` object and find those strings, and try to put it together myself.  But isn't there some official function that ships in the binary to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rebol 3, you can simply use [`FORM`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/form.html) to convert an error! object into its pretty-printed representation:

```
>> err: try [1 / 0]
...

>> form err
== {** Math error: attempt to divide by zero
** Where: / try
** Near: / 0
}
```

Comment: Hrm.  Well, that was easy.

Answer (score 1):

For Rebol2 you can use the following function (I took it from Doc or Gabriele IIRC)

```
form-error: func [
    "Forms an error message"
    errobj [object!] "Disarmed error"
    /all "Use the same format as the REBOL console"
    /local errtype text where
][
    errtype: system/error/(errobj/type)
    text: errtype/(errobj/id)
    if block? text [text: reform bind text errobj]
    either all [
        where: get in errobj 'where
        rejoin [
            "** " errtype/type ": " text newline
            either :where [join "** Where: " [mold :where newline]] [""]
            either errobj/near [join "** Near: " [mold/only errobj/near newline]] [""]
        ]
    ] [text]
]
```

you need to disarm your error:

```
>> print form-error/all disarm try [1 / 0]
** Math Error: Attempt to divide by zero
** Near: 1 / 0
```

Comment: Well that's a mouthful.  Good argument for the Rebol3 method!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own errors like this, where the 'do on the error object arms the error.

```
make-sl4a-error: func [
    message
][
    do make error! [
        type: 'Access
        id: 'Protocol
        arg1: message
    ]
]
```

In Rebol 2, you need to disarm the error before forming

```
>> err: try [ 1 / 0 ]
>> print mold disarm err

make object! [
    code: 400
    type: 'math
    id: 'zero-divide
    arg1: none
    arg2: none
    arg3: none
    near: [1 / 0]
    where: none
]
```

Comment: Nice to know...but that's not what I asked!!  (And there are no armed errors in Rebol3 AFAIK)

Comment: Well, since you had not accepted Earl's answer at the time, I figured you must be asking something else than form or mold on an error! BTW, make error! Just creates an error object. It has to be armed before use.